# Build ios app once, release to multiple devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to deploy an Ios app to multiple Ios devices, without the apple developer program. I found out I can do this relatively easily through Xcode and just physically connecting the device. My issue is that it takes a very long time for the app to build, and I don't want to wait that long for every single device. Is there a way I can build the app once and then just deploy that built version to each device?

Comment: *"without the apple developer program"* - Each MUST be registered with out developer account before the can be deployed as "ad-hoc" builds.  You can then use things Fabric Beta or MS App Centre to handle the distribution.  Your other choice is to use Apple's Test Flight, which will manage the process for you and provide you with the ability to invite more people

Comment: * Unless, of course, you're using a enterprise solution, but I'm not familiar with the release process through that

Comment: I've not tried it with an app that I've built myself, but you _might_ be able to do this locally by installing an IPA file of your app onto the devices using Apple Configurator 2 (or even just iTunes).

Answer (score 0):

If we want to distribute our App in the App Store, we require Apple Developer account. But there’s a good thing we can now test our App on devices without a paid Apple Developer Account. 
For your requirement as per my understanding, follow these steps:

- Modify settings of your app and device on which it is to be tested, as per this link: 
  [Deploying Apps to Devices without an Apple Developer Account](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Deploying-Apps-to-Devices-without-an-Apple-Developer-Account/)
- Clean and prepare a build of app for devices.
- Upload this build on [Diawi](https://diawi.com) and share the link of build to devices for direct install.

Comment: @Felix Ronneberger U got ur solution?